# SQLVDI error when backing up to Azure Storage BLOB

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure

I'm running a patched SQL 2014 trying to backup a database to one of our Azure Storage BLOBs, using:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DB]
TO URL = N'https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/server-mssqlserver/DB.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = N'AzureCredential'
    ,NOFORMAT
    ,NOINIT
    ,NAME = N'DBA_DB-Full Database Backup'
    ,NOSKIP
    ,NOREWIND
    ,NOUNLOAD
    ,COMPRESSION
    ,STATS = 5
GO
```

but the query throws the following error:

> Msg 3292, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   A failure occurred while attempting to execute Backup or Restore with a URL device specified. Consult the Windows Event Log for details.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Checking the server's Event Logs shows the actual error as:

> SQLVDI: Loc=IdentifySQLServer. Desc=MSSQLSERVER. ErrorCode=(5)Access is denied.
>   . Process=4668. Thread=6596. Client. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=.

I have made sure that the **SQL Server Agent** service's account has the **Create global objects** policy, and also made sure the **SQL VSS Writer** service is running under the **Local System** account. The error keeps happening!

Is there something I can do to fix it, or just log some more detailed error messages than the "SQLVDI: Loc=IdentifySQLServer" one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crikey, this is one of those "no idea how I fixed it" things.

Before I went to lunch, I could reliably generate the error in question by running the provided T-SQL, yet when I came back from lunch the BACKUP command completed fine!

The main thing I remember changing was **on the Azure side**, where I created a **SAS (Shared Access Signature)**.

This is supposedly **not required** for SQL 2014 as it uses an actual Azure Credential to connect to the storage instead. I actually created the SAS for an instance of SQL Server 2016 that I want backing up to the same container, and that **may** have opened the access pathway to the container for SQL Server 2014 too!

Many thanks to [Sean Gallardy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41723/sean-gallardy) for recommending [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), which showed a whole ton more error log information than the "ErrorCode=(5)Access is denied" message did.